# Multilayered LSTM in T-fLearn

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tflearn

I'm trying to create a multilayered LSTM in Tf-learn without success.

When doing this

```
a = tflearn.lstm(_input, dropout=0.8, n_units=200, return_seq=True, dynamic=True)
b = tflearn.lstm(a, dropout=0.8, n_units=200, return_seq=False, dynamic=True)
```

I will get a list as output from `a` and the error when training:

```
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py:90: UserWarning: 
 Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
 "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

What is the correct way to do a multilayered LSTM in Tf-learn?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve it? if not, try this:

```
a = tflearn.lstm(_input, 200)
b = tflearn.dropout(a, 0.8)
c = tflearn.lstm(b, 200)
d = tflearn.dropout(c, 0.8)
```